# Do I need to get my bank statements stamped for UK Standard Visitor Visa during Covid-19

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

Last year, I applied for UK Standard Visitor Visa and I submitted my bank statements with stamps from my bank. I also submitted my salary slips stamped by my Employer. I got the visa issued but unfortunately, I couldn't travel due to Covid-19.

I am working from home since last year due to Covid-19. I would be applying for UK Standard Visitor Visa again in couple of weeks. All of my bank accounts are in a different city so I can not travel there to get my bank statements stamped.

I wanted to ask if it is required to stamp the bank statements during the Covid-19 pandemic or I could just print the statements from bank portal and then submit them.

Comment: I don't know if the "stamping" requirement is still in force. If it is, why can't you mail the statements to the bank to be stamped, and have the bank mail back to you the now-stamped statements?

Comment: I think the ‘stamping’ requirement no longer exists given that the current Supporting Documents Guide (published 18 Jan 2021) states “All documents, apart from passports, can be originals, scans or photocopies.” https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica I will check this with my bank.

Comment: @Traveller is it not possible to stamp a photocopy ?

Comment: @Aak Yes, however there is no mention of ‘stamping’ in the Supporting Documents Guide. For a small fee you could email UKVI to ask https://www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi-inside-outside-uk/y

Comment: But save your money; they will just quote from the website and keep your money.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over